# Emacs updating ruby major mode

Tags: ruby, emacs, elisp

I am using emacs 23.1, with the included major mode for ruby.
This regular expression syntax highlighting bug is driving me crazy:
http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/4242

As noted, the bug was fixed in a newer version of ruby-mode.el
I would like to update to this newer version of ruby-mode.el. What is the best method to do this?

What I tried:
1. I installed ruby 1.9.2-p180
2. I verified /ruby-1.9.2-p180/misc/ruby-mode.el was the fixed version
3. I copied it into .emacs.d
4. In my .emacs file I added:

```
(autoload 'ruby-mode "ruby-mode" "Ruby Mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rb$" . ruby-mode))
```

However, the bug is not fixed :(

Any help is appreciated, thank you. Also, if anyone knows, is this fixed in emacs 23.2 or 23.3?

EDIT:
Okay, it turns out it is correctly reading the new ruby-mode.el -- I renamed ruby-mode.elc to ruby-mode.elc2 to make sure this was the case.

Perhaps this is a new edge case, I'm going to file a bug report soon.
Here is the test case for anyone curious

```
method /^"([^"]*)"$/ do |arg|
```

It appears to work correctly with () surrounding the method argument, so that will be my fix for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding explicit path to autoload:

```
(autoload 'ruby-mode "~/.emacs.d/ruby-mode" "Ruby Mode." t)
```

By the way, if you want to know what file is loaded emacs library in, use `M-x locate-library`.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying `ruby-mode.el` to `~/.emacs.d/load/` instead of `~/.emacs.d/`.  That fixed the problem for me.

I think emacs probably looks in `~/.emacs.d/load/` and if it doesn't find the file there it will look elsewhere.  On my system, Ubuntu 10.04, I think it was finding it in `/usr/share/emacs/23.1/lisp/progmodes/ruby-mode.elc`.

Comment: Sadly, the load directory doesn't work. I tried a ruby-mode directory and added that path as well, which also failed. How can I check where emacs finds the ruby-mode? I could definitely use that to make sure it's loading the right file. Thank you.